# UIWebView showing Google Maps cuts off zooming controls

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiwebview, maps

As you can see in the image below, there is a problem showing Google Maps in a `UIWebView` on iPhone having a tab bar and navigation bar.

I searched for parameter to hide the zoomcontrols and only found a javascript api. But I dont know how to use it. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your app will be rejected as the Google logo is hidden breaking the Google license agreement.
If that's  a simple webView (not MKMapView), set it's frame not to be overlaid with a tab-bar.

Regarding the question you asked, the java-script is applied to the webView with [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you. The WebView has the correct size, but the zoomControls and the license logo is hidden/cut off. Even if i set the size of the WebView to 300x300 the zoomControls are completely hidden. I found the same method, but I have no idea what java-script lines to execute. My workaround would be to show the MapView as modal, but that is not that cool.

Comment: It might be helpful to add the placeholder view of the correct frame on the root viewController view to keep the web view there, maybe a scroll view.

Comment: I also added a UIView and called addSubview:webView, but the same issue appeared.